# How can I run two different prefect projects on the same server?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, user-interface, prefect

I have two different projects and I want to run both projects in separate urls.

For example, one project should run at 127.0.0.1:8080 while the other project should run at 127.0.0.1:8081

I created different docker-compose.yml for prefect containers and gave different ports.I created the containers but I can't access it except port 8080.

Is it possible to run two different prefect projects on the same server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you should define port in docker compose file
Example:

```
service:
 container1:
    image: xxx
    container_name: xxx
    ports:
      - "8080:3307"

service:
 container2:
    image: yyy
    container_name: yyy
    ports:
      - "8081:3307"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually implemented the project in the https://github.com/flavienbwk/prefect-docker-compose#run-the-server link. The project only runs on port 8080. I couldn't change the port.

Comment: I cloned this repository and I change the ports in UI Service from 8080:8080/tcp to 8081:8080/tcp (line 139) then it runs on locahost:8081 instead of 8080. You should try

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you're just getting started with Prefect, it would be much easier for you to start with Prefect 2.0 - [here](https://orion-docs.prefect.io/tutorials/orion/) are the docs. You could easily switch between both instances using Profiles https://orion-docs.prefect.io/concepts/settings/#configuration-profiles

Comment: Thank you for the information. actually i have been using it for a long time and if i can find the solution to this problem without upgrading it will be better for me.

Comment: At some point, you will need to upgrade since Prefect 2.0 is the LTS product, so if you are setting up Server now, it sounds like a smart decision to set up Prefect 2.0 already and avoid migration efforts later on

Comment: If i upgrade prefect 2.0, can i run different projects on the same server with different ports? Do you know a simple example of this?

Comment: no, I don't any example for this use case